# Building web services as well as their consumer in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-2, rest

So I'm going to be building two things.  The first is a database-driven collection of RESTful web services.  The second is a user-facing web application which accesses those services.

I have to do this all in Visual Studio 2010, in MVC2 / C#, for deployment to an IIS6 + SQL Server 2005 environment.  I'm not terribly familiar with VS, nor MVC2, nor any of the attendant development and debugging tools.

So, my question is this: How should I structure all this to make life easiest on myself in terms of concurrently developing both pieces?  I need to be able to deploy the two pieces to separate servers, but I want to be able to easily test both of them simultaneously on my development machine.  Do I make two separate projects?  Or is there a way to build a single project with multiple solutions, which can be tested at the same time?

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Just wondering why the MVC>>WebServices>>DB setup?  Are you planning on presenting the app in modes other than web application?

Comment: The web services will be accessed by multiple other applications in the future, some of which will and some of which will not be written on Microsoft technologies, and we want a single point of control for access to the various types of data that the services will provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a single solution containing both web projects for the REST service application (WCF?) and the ASP.NET MVC application and then run them simultaneously using the Visual Studio development server by configuring [multiple startup projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165413.aspx):

[image]

This will allow you to test/debug them simultaneously.

Another possibility is to use the newly released [IIS Express](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx) to host both applications ([you need to install VS 2010 SP1](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/03/vs-2010-sp1-beta-and-iis-developer-express.aspx)) which is the solution I would recommend you.

Comment: I wasn't familiar with WCF, but it looks like exactly what I'm looking for.  So, yes, I suppose I'll be using that.  That said: your suggestion seems like exactly the way to go... thanks!

Comment: I do this, but you will run into issues with CORS. I enabled the proper headers to allow CORS to work in modern browsers, but beware that jQuery's AJAX methods do not support CORS in IE9. There are plugins that enable support in jQuery back to IE8. Further back than that seems to be impossible.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you follow the NerdDinner tutorial. This sample MVC2 application follows the suggested pattern for developing MVC2 web applications that use services.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/introducing-the-nerddinner-tutorial